# ServiceStack request giving 500 for large request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack with MVC4 and getting 500 error when request parameters are long. I am posting ProductIds seperated by commas to controller via AJAX. In controller I have following call to servicestack API to retrieve data.

```
ResponseDTO res = restClient.Get(new RequestDTO { ProductIDs = ids});
//ResponseDTO res = restClient.Get(new RequestDTO { ProductIDs = "1234,1235,1236"});
```

If i submit small parameters in above, it works fine with no error. But when parameter string is in range of 1800 characters, it simply fails on above line and gives 500 Internal Server Error:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/Products/GetProducts

Exception Details: ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.WebServiceException: Not Found
```

is there a limit on GET method for posting large parameter request? Why does it fail for large request when for small parameters it successfully calls API, retrieves data via SQL procedure and sends to view correctly. What can I look into to solve this? Thank you!

p.s. when i debug via VS2012, i see exception details I see Message:Not Found and StatusCode: 404.

Comment: You shouldn't use GET requests with long data. Urls have varying length restrictions in different browsers. Some browsers don't support GET requests over 2KB, which `in the range of 1800 characters` gets close to. What happens if you POST? It may be an issue with ServiceStack but it's unlikely, as the `string` class will easily handle 2000 characters.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Please post your DTO. I managed to send a string of at least 13000 characters without issue using GET.

Comment: We have GET methods in Services projects as interface and havent implemented POST. So I am getting "Method not allowed" error. I will try to change POST all places and see if it works. and Yes they are string and being serialized when post via AJAX json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott mentioned above, we tried POST for all methods and it fixed issue. I knew GET had limit on browser URL length but didnt think it matters as we had ServiceStack framework and all of their examples were using GET. Thanks again Scott.